# RequireJS config for JQuery lib with specific version

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have pretty basic setting for  requirejs config,

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/libs',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jquery: 'jquery-1.9.1'                
    }  
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery'],
function ($, ui, app) {

});
```

my jquery file (jquery-1.9.1.js) is located under libs folder
everything seems like in official documentation but in browser I see next error:

> GET http://mysite/Scripts/jquery.js req.load @
>   require.js:1926context.load @ require.js:1667Module.load @
>   require.js:829Module.fetch @ require.js:819Module.check @
>   require.js:851Module.enable @ require.js:1165context.enable @
>   require.js:1538(anonymous function) @ require.js:1150(anonymous
>   function) @ require.js:131each @ require.js:56Module.enable @
>   require.js:1102Module.init @ require.js:783(anonymous function) @
>   require.js:1441 require.js:165 Uncaught Error: Script error for:
>   jquery

I saw in official doc that next message I just need to understend why my case is not working

> The other (recommended) solution is to just name the file 'jquery.js'
>   and place it in the baseUrl directory. Then the above paths entry is
>   not needed.

Comment: Check your application directory structure, seems that problem in app path specified

Comment: I did it 100 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a require.js project, I always import jQuery through:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
         'jquery': '[path to jquery]',
    },
    shim: {
         'jquery': {
             exports: '$'
         }
    }
});
```

In your case, I'd also try first without `baseUrl`, and when only when it works, try to set up the configuration with baseUrl.